# Twitter bootstrap - how to remove gradient mixin in subclass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, css

I want to subclass .navbar-inner in my custom theme, but I can't figure a non-hackish way to disable gradient (apart from setting both gradient colors to same color which seems dirty). Any idea how can I override (disable) a mixin from a subclass in less??

Answer (score 14):

That's what you need to achieve in css to override disable the gradient.

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-inner {
  background-color: #2c2c2c; 
  background-image: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: none;
}
```

`background-image: none;` has to be used several times to override all the vendor prefixes.

[image: remove gradient]

Comment: Does this give any performance advantage over actually having single-color gradient? :)

Comment: @pielgrzym an override with a  single color gradient will do the trick. but no performance advantage or so small, you can't even noticed it.

Comment: "background-image: none; has to be used several times to override all the vendor prefixes." that is wrong! the last wins, so one time is enough. In your example you overwrite 5 times your own definition one line before.

Comment: What @TLindig said. It has no effect if you just repeat the same declaration over and over again. Only the last one will be applied. To override vendor-prefixed declarations, you actually have to do with using that exact property (e.g. `-webkit-box-shadow`).

Answer (score 5):

For SASS code:
I added background-color:transparent and moved it into a mixin

```
@mixin override_gradient_vertical() {
  background-color:transparent;
  background-image: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: none;
}
```

Now you just can use

```
@include override_gradient_vertical();
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the solution. Just sharing what I came up with after reading the answers:

This is the SCSS I'm using to remove a simple gradient:

```
@mixin remove_gradient($color:transparent) {
    background-color:$color;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: none;
}
```

Note that you can pass a color to the mixin (was needed on my case):

```
@include remove_gradient(white);
```

Or let it default to transparent:

```
@include remove_gradient();
```

Answer (score 1):

for what its worth here is a **less implementation**.
bootstrap files mixin.less

```
#gradient{
    .remove(@color: transparent) {
        background-color:@color;
        background-image: none;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        filter: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradient is added by the bootstrap_theme file.

I really didn't like the idea of having so many background-image to none. So my solution is if you are using SASS or LESS version of bootstrap, just override gradient by the following lines originally present in _theme.scss

FROM

```
.navbar-default {
  @include gradient-vertical($start-color: lighten($navbar-default-bg, 10%), $end-color: $navbar-default-bg);
  @include reset-filter(); // Remove gradient in IE<10 to fix bug where dropdowns don't get triggered
  border-radius: $navbar-border-radius;
  $shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.15), 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
  @include box-shadow($shadow);

  .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    @include gradient-vertical($start-color: darken($navbar-default-bg, 5%), $end-color: darken($navbar-default-bg, 2%));
    @include box-shadow(inset 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.075));
  }
}
```

TO

```
.navbar-default {
  @include gradient-vertical($start-color: $navbar-default-bg, $end-color: $navbar-default-bg);
  @include reset-filter(); // Remove gradient in IE<10 to fix bug where dropdowns don't get triggered

  $shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.15), 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
  @include box-shadow($shadow);

  .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    @include gradient-vertical($start-color: $navbar-default-bg, $end-color: $navbar-default-bg);
    @include box-shadow(inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.075));
  }
}
```

As you can see, the start and end point are the same value, thus we would never see the gradient effect.Simple and Clean.